# Mongodb: "Error: error doing query: failed: network error while attempting to run command 'find' on host '127.0.0.1:53492' "

Tags: mongodb

Every time I try to execute the "Find" command on mongodb I get that error. But it only appears when I query data from certain collections.

Comment: You will have to provide more element if you want someone to help you on your issue. Piece of code leading to the error, logs, mongodb database and collection name... Please refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: db.getCollection('picklists').find({})


When I try to execute that command on Robo 3T I get the error message on the topic. Could it be caused by the fact that im trying to get 14000 records at once

Comment: what version of mongodb do you use? do you have SSL enabled? what does the log say?

Comment: Its version 3.4.5 and No SSL is not enabled.  I'm actually using SSH instead of SSL

Comment: Find the log and edit your post with the relative error log line